# Selected not working in html.dropdownlist MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code

> person.State is Nullable string

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.States = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "", Text = "Please select", Selected = string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.State)},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "ACT", Text = "ACT", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "act"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "NSW", Text = "NSW", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "nsw"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "NT", Text = "NT", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "nt"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "QLD", Text = "QLD", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "qld"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "SA", Text = "SA", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "sa"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "TAS", Text = "TAS", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "tas"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "VIC", Text = "VIC", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "vic"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "WA", Text = "WA", Selected = person.State.ToLower() == "wa"}
            };
```

**View:**

```
@{
 List<SelectListItem> states = ViewBag.States;
}
...
...
...
  @Html.DropDownList("State", states, new { id = "State", @class = "roleSelect" })
```

Even though one `SelectListItem` is `Selected=true`, in the output it is showing `Please select`. When I inspect the element in html output, none of the `option` has `Select` attribute.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does your model have a property named `State`? If so setting the `Selected` property is pointless. Your binding to a property so if the value of `State` is (say) `"NSW"`, then the 3rd option will be selected (that's how binding works). Also delete the first `SelectListIem` and use the overload that accepts an optionLabel. And remove the `id = "State"` - the helper already adds that anyway

Comment: And you can just replace all that code with `ViewBag.States = new SelectList(new List<String>() { "ACT", "NSW", "NT", .... "WA" });` and in the view, `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, (SelectList)ViewBag.States, "-Please select-", new { @class = "roleSelect" })`